# Dividir una cadena de caracteres por un caracter especial y que respete los espacios en blanco

Tags: java, split

Estoy tratando de separar esta cadena de caracteres **1&Posgrado&Maria Sarmiento&25&Maestria en economia&Ninguna&Investigacion** separándolo por el caracter **&** pero al usar el método split() me está separando la cadena de esta manera:

1
Posgrado
Maria

Es decir que llega hasta Maria. No sé si existe alguna manera en la que me respete el espacio de los caracteres y realice la separación como la necesito, que es solo por el &.

```
        String comando;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        comando = sc.next();
        String [] pruebaComando;
        pruebaComando = comando.split("&");
        for(int i = 0; i < pruebaComando.length; i++){
            System.out.println(pruebaComando[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Llega solo hasta maría porque tu input tiene un salto de línea? Estás seguro de que el `sc.next();` está cogiendo todo el string hasta Investigacion? Porque el `split("&");` no debería separar por espacios, solo por el string indicado... Es muy importante ***probar e investigar*** antes de preguntar... Así a simple vista, juraría que el método `sc.next()`  no te está cogiendo todo el input, y eso es algo que tienes que probar tú antes de preguntar. Prueba a usar el `nextLine()` tal como sugiere @Dramaturgo, debería cogerte todo lo que ingreses sin tokenizar

Comment: usa nextLine(); ...next captura solo hasta llegar a un espacio

Comment: Correcto, era por el Next(), con NextLine() sí lo toma completo. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

yo lo haría así:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

public class Pruebas {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String comando = "1&Posgrado&Maria Sarmiento&25&Maestria en economia&Ninguna&Investigacion";
    String[] pruebaComando;
    pruebaComando = comando.split(Pattern.quote("&"));
    for (String s : pruebaComando) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

}

Espero que no te moleste que cambié un poco el código.